# How do I get just the accelerometer X, Y, Z values without having an updating value in android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Hi I have a class that basically gathers GPS data (Longitude, Lattitude, and Bearing), Time (in H, M, and S), and accelerometer data (X,Y,Z) all on button click. So far I have gotten the GPS stuff to work (except Bearing for some reason only shows 0?? Do I need to set some special permissions for this??) and the time to show at the instant the Button is clicked, but the accelerometer X,Y,and Z are constantly changing because they are tied with a listener. Is there a method like getX(), getY(), or getZ() that will give me just one X,Y,Z reading on button click without it changing everytime. Here is my code so far:

```
package com.example.servicetest3;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

protected LocationManager locationManager;    
protected Button retrieveLocationButton;
protected TextView displayView;

//accelerometer vars
Sensor accelerometer;
SensorManager sm;
TextView acceleration;
TextView time;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);
    displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayView);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener()
    );

    //time
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    //set up Accelerometer service and its corresponding textViews
    acceleration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acceleration);
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
            int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int second = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);
            time.setText(Integer.toString(hour) + " | " + Integer.toString(minute) + " | " + Integer.toString(second));
        }
});        

}    

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {

        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s \n Bearing: %3$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getBearing()
        );
        displayView.setText(message);

        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}   

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s \n Bearing: %3$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getBearing()
        );
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

//accelerometer
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   acceleration.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + 
                        "\nY: " + event.values[1] +
                        "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Please help ASAP!!! Thanks!

Comment: I would think you would have to be moving for getBearing() to return anything. It's mis-named anyway, what it really returns is your track.

Comment: even when im moving i get nothing? also is there another way then to get an accurate bearing reading? thanks

Comment: How much are you moving? The GPS filters the data so you have to be moving in the same direction for a bit before it considers it stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unregister the listener in `onSensorChanged()` after you get your values.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    acceleration.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + 
                        "\nY: " + event.values[1] +
                        "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);

    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I think I figured it out. I basically just created three floats that are stored with the x,y,z vals in the onSensorChanged() and then printed out just in the onCreate() method. Also as far as your approach goes, I want different or I guess, current X,Y,Z on each button click. The method you described above would just get it once and then keep that. But thanks anyway. Any ideas on why the Bearing isn't working??